# Extracting data from Table to do arithmetic operations

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a code, which goes like this:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

c = Table[{x, 2 x, 0 x, N[Sqrt[x]], 0 x}, {x, 0, 20, 2}];

headings = Join[{{"x", "2*x", "imag1", "sqrt(x)", "imag2"}}, c];

Export["file.dat", headings];

const1 = 2;
const2 = 3;
```

The output is extracted to a dat file “file.dat” which looks like this:

[image]

Now I need to take each element in the second column, subtract the value of first column from this one and then multiply by a constant and then whole of this value divide by another constant defined in the program. All this value should be collected in another column, say D.

E.g. $D2=\frac{(x2-B2)\times const1}{const2}$, $D3=\frac{(x3-B3)\times const1}{const2}$, and so on. Similarly, I need to do it for forth column. 
Ideally, I am expecting the output to look like this:

[image]

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `const2` is undefined and `const1` is defined twice.

Comment: @Roman it was a typo and has been corrected. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if you can use this

```
tbl = Table[{x, 2 x, 0 x, N[Sqrt[x]], 0 x}, {x, 0, 20, 2}];
const1 = 2.;
const2 = 3.;
newrow[{a_,b_,c_,d_,e_}]:={a,b,c,(b-a)*const1/const2,d,e,(c-b)*const1/const2};
newtbl=Map[newrow,tbl];
headings = {"x", "2*x", "imag1", "sqrt(x)", "imag2"};
Export["file.dat",Join[{headings},newtbl]]
```

That `Map` is going to construct a new row from an existing row and do that for every row in your existing table creating a new table.

Comment: This is it. Thanks a lot.